# How to convert ETH ethereum transaction value to decimal in javascript

Tags: ethereumj

Example value: `0x2c1c986f1c48000`

from: [here](https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getBlockByNumber&tag=latest&boolean=true&apikey=)

Expected value back: `0.19866144` Eth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ether fixed point numbers are higher precision than javascript floats, so you will need to use a library that supports those bigger values.

In Web3 you can simply do:

```
let bigNumber = web3.toBigNumber('0xFFFFFF')
web3.fromWei(bigNumber)
```

Comment: I come up with: `parseInt(0x2c1c986f1c48000, 16) / Math.pow(10, 18)` [link](http://i91.fastpic.ru/big/2017/1020/03/1de8f089741ed4d8e4b0023525cc6d03.png)

Answer (score 2):

Try this with [ethers.js utils](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/display-logic/#utils-formatEther):

```
ethers.utils.formatEther('1000000000000000000') // return 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [BigNumber library](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/):

```
var value_wei = "0x2c1c986f1c48000";
var value_ether = new BigNumber(value_wei).dividedBy(new BigNumber("1000000000000000000");
```

To explain: Ethereum works with units of wei. 1 ether is 1e18 wei, so you have to deal numbers that are too large to be handled by javascript. The BigNumber library  accepts representation of numbers a strings, so you can go around this problem.

Note that all functions in web3.js always return values in wei as a BigNumber object, so the return of web3.eth.getBalance(...) can be directly used with the lines above, for example.